# Magento is sending confirmation emails to all email addresses except site admin's

Tags: magento, email

My Magento site has been sending order confirmations to all email addresses except for the admin email address of the site. I questioned if a spam filter was the real issue and Magento does not appear to be hitting any errors, but I'm not seeing any kind of exception through Magento. Has anyone else experienced issues with order confirmation emails for orders placed with the admin account for Magento?

Comment: For testing, if you change your admin email address for sales to a third party such as gmail, do it work? Is your email address server the same as your domain name (eg site:www.abc.com email sales@abc.com) and are you hosting your mail server else where such as google apps?

Comment: There is a separate stackexchange dedicated to Magento: http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: R.S. - yes, it works with third party domains. The issue seems to be limited to email addresses sharing the same domain name as my site. However, I can receive other emails at this account. The only problem is emails originating from my site.

Comment: Where is your mail server hosted, on the same server as your web server or using a third party service like google apps?

Answer (score -1):

We bumped into the same problem. I must say it did confuse us for quite a while. Basically, if it works with third party domains, all you need to do is to disable **`postfix` local delivery**.

In order to do that, please refer here: https://serverfault.com/questions/137591/postifx-disable-local-delivery

Here's an *excerpt* from our main.cf file:

```
myhostname = www.someshop.co.uk (this is obviously not real)
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination =
relayhost = smtp.mailgun.org:25 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
```

We left `mydestination` blank to do it. *Magic.*